# Configure a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have the following data: Each ID has one Name and one number of followers. For instance, the name of `tie123` is `Tie`, and its number of followers is `20`.

I want to make a pivot table, which matches this structure (but I have other data around that I don't show here). The pivot table in the screenshot is not what I want for two reasons:

1. I want a Name could be in the same row as an ID, for instance, I want `Amber` to be on the right of `Amber456`.
2. I want to show `Followers` rather than `Sum of Followers`.

Does anyone know how to configure the pivot table?

[image]

Comment: *I want to show `Followers` rather than `Sum of Followers`* If `ID` is unique then these values are equal. Or you tell about header name, not about value? if so simply rename it... *I want Amber to be on the right of Amber456* Move `Name` to values instead of row groups, and select any function applicable to string value (`MAX`, for example).

Comment: "Move Name to values instead of row groups, and select any function applicable to string value (MAX, for example)." ==> it all shows `0` rather than a name.

Comment: Oh, sorry... really the values are treated as numbers unconditionally. If so try to use [Calculate values in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) - maybe it allows to obtain the value you need (maybe using UDF, for example, with VLOOKUP in).